# Doing good deeds and being Islam-abiding out of fear of punishment and disliking it

Tags: deeds

Assalamo3alaykom, I would like to ask about an issue I don't have clear ideas about, as it is something that I found no answer for.

Anyone is judged by their own deeds and related niyyah, and outer deeds are definitely something that are hold into account, and by outer deeds are meant also those who are performed alone, but what if the intention is not that sound or likewise isn't the heart?
There's a clear difference between a good deed made in front of people in order to show off, and a good deed made alone sincerely in order to seek Allah's pleasure, but the performer doesn't like doing the deed in the first place, even it is done sincerely, because one may perform a deed sincerely and alone (this would confirm sincerety), so from that point of view a distinction could be made between Niyyah and love of the act, even if the latter definitely entails the former, but not necessarily viceversa, but I'm not sure whether the Niyyah is totally related to loving to do that deed.
So my questions are these

1) if a person does a good deed alone and makes sure nobody sees them, but dislikes to do that deed and forces themselves, can the person be considered to perform the deed sincerely?

2) If a person tries to abide by some Islamic principles, rules and regulations, abides by them correctly and not for showing off, but doesn't like to comply by them because of their own nature, are they blameworthy? And how can they be blameworthy since that's their own nature?

3) Will Allah judge the servant according to what they have done in terms of good deeds sincerely even if the servant didn't like them in their heart and forced themselves not to manifest that dislike, or will He also judge them by the state of their heart? This question excludes deeds done for people's sake and to show off.

4) How will Allah judge a person who performed good deeds and forced themselves to perform them, but without pleasure?

5)If a person didn't harm anyone, didn't steal and didn't oppress anyone whatsoever, but they have a filthy and evil heart, will they be punished even according to the state of their heart alone, even if they didn't act upon it? Does Allah judge on the basis of deeds (assumed that are not for showing off) only or over the basis of the heart as well?

Summarising, what's the ruling over a person who tries to perform hasanat and abide by Islam as much as they can just for fear of the hell-fire but dislikes it all together? How can a person, in case, be possibly held accountable despite they obeyed Allah as much as they can out of fear only?

Please, read the question carefully and don't tell me that it is a contradiction. Thank you.

Comment: What example of good a deed that you can do sincerely but dislike it?

Comment: There are many. As above, I said that one may do a thing alone, and this would confirm sincerity and not ostentation, but dislike it because he's forcing himself to do that.

Comment: One for example may study for a test sincerely alone and not to show off, but dislike it.

Comment: Honestly, my brother, I personally don't think that its easy for me to do something like that. I only really start to embrace Islam quite recently, just a few years ago and I don't feel I'm being forced to do anything in regards of Islam teachings. Probably you haven't understand some things yet that's why you feel the way you feel. But I think it's also normal to sometime have that kind of feeling, it makes you think that Allah is trying to tell you something. I think and hope you will find answer from the Quran and Hadith.

Comment: It's not me that I feel that way otherwise I would've said it

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry I misunderstand to thinking that it was you. I once ask a friend of mine this one question = "What do we call a person who is Islam but doesn't practice Islam?" which he he replied "It's not in our power or position to label someone because we don't know the future and we don't know Allah's plan, and Allah knows best".